# Find the volume of the solid interior to both $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid interior to both $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$?

So I came up with

$$2\int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi}\int_{r = 1}^{2 \cos(\theta)}\sqrt{4-r^2}\,r\, dr\, d \theta$$

My question is how did you get $\theta$ from $0$ to $pi$ and not $0$ to $2\pi$?
What would you do to find it?

Comment: How did you come up with that if you don't understand how you came up with that?

Comment: use spherical coordinates.

Comment: It was actually from the notes... but that's not the point though.... how is it from 0 to pi?

Comment: Do you know your region in the $xy$-plane?

Answer (score 1):

$(x-1)^2+ y^2 = 1$ translates to $r^2 - 2r\cos \theta + 1 = 1\Rightarrow r=2cos\theta$. To integrate over this area we must cover the whole circle. Write down the values of $r$ for $\theta = 0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}$ and $2\pi$. You'll see that the circle is traversed twice. Therefore, we only need to integrate from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: I believe the lower limit of integration in the $r$ direction should be $0$ instead of $1$.